# How to check aadhar number is been already register with another user or not without storing aadhar number

Tags: backend

I work for a vehicle rental company and am building an app where people can register and do their KYC with an Aadhar card(every Indian citizen has this ID card which comes with a 12-digit unique non-changeable number) and Driving License.
The process of KYC is that at first they will enter their mobile number and then they will enter their Aadhar card number and I will post the request containing the Aadhar card number to a third-party service which sends the opt to the Aadhar card linked mobile number of the user and I will take that OTP and again send it to third party service which verifies and give me the detail of the user (name, dob, address, gender).
Now as per government rule, any company/organisation cannot store an Aadhar number (we can store the last 4 digits of it). Due to this, a user can create multiple accounts with multiple phone numbers(I am checking if the phone number is already in my database or not) and with the same Aadhar card(since I cannot store Aadhar number, I cannot check if Aadhar number is already in my database or is already verified/associated with any other user or not).

my backend is in node js and the database is MongoDB